# How to keep track of a / a + b?

Tags: algorithm, dictionary

I want to keep track of the ratio `a/(a+b)` over time. The values of a and b are increasing over time. The increments are stored in dictionaries where the keys represent discrete time. Example:

```
a = {1:1, 15:1, 17:2, 21:1, ..}
b = {1:1, 4:1, 13:2, 22:1, ..}
```

The output should be

```
ratio = {1:1/2, 4:1/3, 13:1/5, 15:2/6, 17:4/11, 21:5/9, 22:5/10, ..}
```

What are your suggestions for computing `ratio` from `a` and `b`?

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty standard event-based simulation pattern. You'll need to turn the input maps into "events," sort them by time of occurrence, then process them in time order to track the numerator and denominator.  When the sorted times take a jump, it's time to emit an output value.  The last detail is to makes sure to emit the final value if there's one "waiting" for a jump that hasn't yet occurred when the data are exhausted. Something like this:

```
def track(a, b):
  # Events are triples: (a/b, time, value).
  events = map(
      lambda item: ('a', item[0], item[1]), a.items()) + map(
      lambda item: ('b', item[0], item[1]), b.items())
  events.sort(key = lambda item: item[1])
  num = 0
  den = 0
  t = events[1][1]
  result = {}
  for event in events:
    t_new = event[1]
    # If the previous time step has ended, emit its fraction.
    if t_new != t:
      result[t] = str(num) + '/' + str(den)
      t = t_new
    # Update the fraction.
    den += event[2]
    if event[0] == 'a':
      num += event[2]
  # Emit the final time step.
  if t not in result:
    result[t] = str(num) + '/' + str(den)
  return result

a = {1:1, 15:1, 17:2, 21:1};
b = {1:1, 4:1, 13:2, 22:1};

print track(a, b)
```

And then...

```
$ python foo.py
{1: '1/2', 4: '1/3', 13: '1/5', 15: '2/6', 17: '4/8', 21: '5/9', 22: '5/10'}
```

Comment: My solution is very similar: first compute dictionaries of cumulative values of a and b and then create events and then create the result dictionary. The publish part I solved by asking if the key `t` is already in the `result` dictionary instead of using two variables `t` and `t_new`.

Comment: uh, i think my "asking if the key t is already in the result" is not correct..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the key abstraction here is a *step function*, which can be naturally defined much like a list:

```
data Step a = Step a Time (Step a)
```

A value `Step x t rest` represents a step function that takes the value `x` until time `t`, after which it behaves as the step function `rest`.  You will want to implement `Functor` on it so you have `fmap`, and then the key algorithm is an analogue of `zip`:

```
zipStep :: Step a -> Step b -> Step (a,b)
zipStep (Step x t rest) (Step x' t' rest') = ...
   -- a step function with value (x,x') until the earlier of 
   -- the two times, with a recursive call to zipStep for the remainder
```

Once you have this, you can define your ratio easily

```
astep :: Step Int  -- build these by sorting your input
bstep :: Step Int

ratio :: Step Rational
ratio = fmap (\(a,b) -> a % (a + b)) (zipStep astep bstep)
```

Comment: what language is this?

Comment: @LeeviL, Oh sorry, this is haskell.  I basically only ever see haskell questions so I just assumed this was one.  Oops.  Probably not a good solution to your problem in any other language. :-p